# Youtube video player

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Is this possible to allow just a specific website to display a youtube video
with the iframe embeded code? or with the api

Comment: I'm going to switch on wistia for my video it allow what I asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the iframe code alone it is not possible. Your youtube-video displayed on the youtube website. As long as anyone can view this video by going to youtube like thishttp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJjg4JweJZU

for example, anyone can embedd it using an iframe.

What you could do is limit the acces to this video itself. As far as I remember you could specify whether anyone or just your friends can whatch your video.

The latter case may not keep people from embedding your video, but it will keep them from viewing it as long as they are not logged in to youtube and are your friends there.